# The type or namespace name "..." could not be found - Unity Vuforia

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am pretty new to Unity and Vuforia. I am trying to do solve this following problem. I have a script file that I am using for 2 different Image targets. Only 1 script should be running at a time. So i opened "DefaultObserverEventHandler.cs" to handle tracking events. I want to disable the script on that particular Image target when the tracking is lost. But when i try to get a reference on the script "QuizzBehaviour" i get an error. "QuizzBehaviour" is located in my Assets folder. Thanks in advance.[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please add code as text, not images. Indicate the line of error with a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it. I made my own "DefaultObserverEventHandler.cs" script and placed it in the same folder where my "QuizzBehaviour.cs" script is.

Answer (score 0):

"Find" will search through objects in scene not in your folders.However, at all costs you should avoid searching for objects by typing their name manually.In your case, the matter is quite simple. You can either add a script to an object and then use the get component command, or you can make an abstract class and refer to it.